# Get AJAX Request and Looping Through JSON

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I am using a GET ajax request to retrieve some JSON data from the database. I want to loop through it and print certain items. For example, I want to print all the address in `stylist_1` only. The problem is that it only prints the last item.

Here's what the code looks like:

```
var stylist1Addresses;

    function getData() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/getData',
            type: 'GET',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.stylist_1.length; i++) {
                    stylist1Addresses = data.stylist_1[i];
                }
            }
        });
        console.log(stylist1Addresses);
    }
```

Sample data:

```
{
  "stylist_1": [
    {
      "Address": "1 Stn Main", 
      "Phone": "403-990-9033"
    }, 
    {
      "Address": "474 Cirrus Rd", 
      "Phone": "403-995-3243"
    }, 
    {
      "Address": "1591 Stn St", 
      "Phone": "403-982-8893"
    }
  ], 
  "stylist_2": [
    {
      "Address": "219 Welch Blvd", 
      "Phone": "587-436-3171"
    }, 
    {
      "Address": "374 Main Rd", 
      "Phone": "587-315-9431"
    }, 
    {
      "Address": "564 Main Rd", 
      "Phone": "403-938-9983"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm oversimplifying this but do you mean to have the console statement inside the loop?

Comment: If not maybe you should use an array to store the values instead.

stylist1Addresses[] = data.stylist_1[i];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two possible solutions.

First solution:

```
var stylist1Addresses;

    function getData() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/getData',
            type: 'GET',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.stylist_1.length; i++) {
                    stylist1Addresses = data.stylist_1[i];
                    console.log(stylist1Addresses);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

This will produce three console logs, one of each address.

Second solution:

```
var stylist1Addresses = [];

function getData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/getData',
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.stylist_1.length; i++) {
                stylist1Addresses.push(data.stylist_1[i]);
            }
            console.log(stylist1Addresses);
        }
    });
}
```

This will produce one console log, an array of all three addresses.

Which were you looking for?

Comment: Thank you Jasen, I've fixed it.

Comment: Thank you! I was looking for the first solution, but it's nice to know about the second solution as well. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You are updating the 'stylist1Addresses' variable with each loop.

try to initialize the 'stylist1Addresses' variable as an array like this:

```
var stylist1Addresses = [];
```

and replace this line:

```
stylist1Addresses = data.stylist_1[i];
```

with this:

```
stylist1Addresses.push(data.stylist_1[i]);
```

'push' will add the item on each loop to the 'stylist1Addresses' array.

**Note:** if you want to get the address only you should use this line instead

```
stylist1Addresses.push(data.stylist_1[i].Address);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how i will print the addresses in stylist_1 only

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
   var $string = '{THE JSON Here}';
   $json = $.parseJSON($string);
   for ( var i in $json ) {
      if ( i === 'stylist_1') {
        var list = $json[i];
        console.log(list[0].Address);
        return;
      }
    }
</script>
```